# Erlang cuttlefish schema for nested list of configuration items

Tags: erlang, schema

I am trying to generate cuttlefish schema ( [github cuttlefish](https://github.com/basho/cuttlefish)) for the following  proplist configuration structure.

I have several machine entries and under each machine entry there 
are several ip entries.

```
[{machines,
[{machine1, [
    {mach_id, "BeeHive"},
    {ram, "2G"},
    {ips, [
        {ip1, [
        {ip, "IP1"},
        {sessions, 10}
        ]},
        ----,
        ---- ]}
    ]},
{machine2, [
    {mach_id, "BeeHive2"},
    {ram, "2G"},
    {ips, [
        {ip1, [
        {ip, "IP1"},
        {sessions, 11}
        ]}, 
        ----, 
        ---- ]}
    ]}
]
}].
```

In cuttlefish mapping configuration, this requires multiple $ variables and for nested listing like several ip entries inside machine entry .

Please provide any pointers towards making a schema for the 
above listed proplist structure.